# can i fill a shape with stripes or dots in android 2d

Tags: android, 2d, paint

I want to draw a simple shape - oval, rectangle, triangle - and fill it with stripes or dots.
How can i do it in android? what is the simplest way?

Thank You.

PS, Does using 'Path' is the simplest way to draw a triangle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BitmapShader to do what you want. Just use a repeatable bitmap. Path is the easiest way to draw a filled triangle yes.